# How to create incremented view filters for numeric fields in Drupal?

Tags: views

In my Drupal 7 I'm building a view of homes/properties with exposed filters of "Minimum Rent" and "Maximum Rent" - so that people can find homes according to their budget.

Rent (per month) is basically an integer number field and can be whichever number (£475 or £677 or whatever an end user enters when creating the node). But in my exposed filters for "Min Rent" and "Max Rent" I want it to be a dropdown list of £100, £200, £300, £400, £500 etc -in other words, automatically **incremented**. Exactly as we see on websites like www.rightmove.co.uk or www.zoopla.com or any other property listing website.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a field an select a type of text list using a list widget, you can create the any list you wish for the field.  Then when you expose the field in your view  the drop down list of values will be included in the exposed filter.

Comment: That's not what I'm after because my field type is numeric (price) and can be anything, thus the selection list for the field is out of the question - you can't ask people to rent out their house for specifically £200 when they want to receive £245 for example.

I have created a custom module here http://groups.drupal.org/node/25941#comment-746878  but it doesn't seem to work in D7.  Perhaps you can help in improving its code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use hybrid exposed filters as a starting point. It is a work in progress patch but very mature. See:

- http://drupal.org/node/731662
- http://vimeo.com/14533078